# R - Histogram / density plot of data in data frame

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I'm sure there is an obvious and easy solution for this ... but I'm drawing a complete blank on this one: how can I create a histogram and/or density plot using ALL data points in a data set that consists of several rows and columns?

Example data:

```
MYdata <- data.frame(Name = round(rnorm(12, 1000, 250)), 
                     Sample1 = rnorm(12, 10000, 2500), 
                     Sample2 = rnorm(12, 10000, 2500), 
                     Sample3 = rnorm(12, 10000, 2500), 
                     Sample4 = rnorm(12, 10000, 2500))
```

"Name" is the header of the column containing the row names. Columns Sample1 to Sample4 contain the data.  `hist()` or `geom_histogram()` require an x = .  But I don't know what x is in my data set.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out `melt` from the `reshape2` package.  Since Hadley made them both `reshape2`, `plyr` and `ggplot` they play very nicely together:

```
MYdata.melt <- melt(MYdata, id.vars='Name')

ggplot(MYdata.melt, aes(x=value, color=variable)) + geom_density()
```

I used `geom_density()` since your data is continuous, but changing to `geom_histogram()` is straight forward.

Comment: I was having a hard time with this.  I think that melt is in the reshape package: http://had.co.nz/reshape/